# Computation on large data file without MapReduce.

Tags: algorithm, multiprocessing, large-data

I have a file containing a million word vector. The dimension of each vector is 300.

For example:
***dataFile.txt***

**word1 [0.1 0.2 0.8 ...... 300th value]**

**word2 [0.3 0.4 0.6 ...... 300th value]**

**...**
**...**

**upto million**

I have to perform  operation between each possible pairs of 2 words taken at a time, that would be approximately n*n = million times million computations.

I have just 16GB of RAM and 4 cores. I would write python code that can perform quick computation using the available memory and cpu cores.  Would you please help 
with possible strategy i should follow. No mapreduce please.

Comment: Given https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock, you may find it easiest to design the bulk of your application as several independent processes, perhaps producing output files somewhere that something else can read and paste together to create the final answer.

Comment: check out word2vec (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) he uses the same kind of word embeddings and everything there is Very optimized. I'm sure he has something to fit your bill